# Detect when iAd does not come up

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod, iad

the fill rate for iAds on the iPad is horrendous. On one of my iPhone apps, the fill rate is 90%. On the iPad, it is 4%, and I got 1,500 requests already today! That's money lost. How can I detect when an iAd does not appear so that I can replace it with an ad from AdMob? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:)

Comment: Is there a way to make it fall in Simulator (excluding disconnecting WiFi) to test the alternatives (as display an AdMob banner)?

Comment: @Matte.Car Settings -> Developer -> Fill Rate